# Should I also implement a CMOS clock oscillator's load circuit to my PCB?

Tags: oscillator

I am trying to use a CMOS Clock Oscillator (SM7745HEV) as a clock input for my ADC. When the clock arrived, I tested it with an oscilloscope to verify its frequency. As shown on the datasheet, I used the following circuit when I tested it.
[image]

Now that I have verified the oscillator and want to implement it with my ADC, should I remove the load resistance and capacitance?

If yes, then I assume that my ADC right will replace the load resistance and capacitance, right? Then, should I also check if the ADC matches the recommended resistance and capacitance value?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 5kΩ resistance and the load capacitor are there to verify that the device meets the published performance specifications under worst case conditions, and you don't need them at all. The device will oscillate at the correct frequency with or without them.

If you include them in your final design, all you are doing is wasting power in the resistor, and distorting what would otherwise have been a nice 0V/+3.3V output, with clean and fast transitions.

Remove them, this load is for testing purposes only, and isn't necessary for the oscillator to work in the final design. And no, the ADC won't provide such a load.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and the explanation